# How can I see raw bytes stored in a MySQL column?

Tags: mysql, perl, encoding

I have a MySQL table properly set to the UTF-8 character set.  I suspect some data inserted into one of my columns has been double encoded.  I am expecting to see a non-breaking space character (UTF-8 0xC2A0), but what I get when selecting this column out of this table is four octets (0xC3A2 0xC2A0).  That's what I would expect to see if at some point somebody had treated an UTF-8 0xC2A0 as ISO-8859-1 then attempted to encode again to UTF-8 before inserting into MySQL.

My test above where I am seeing the four octets involves selecting this column out of MySQL with Perl's DBD::mysql.  I'd like to take Perl and DBD::mysql out of the equation to verify that those four octets are actually what MySQL has stored.  Is there a way to do this directly with a SQL query?

Comment: HEX did it, and looks like I was right about the double encoding in the table.  I'll need to look at the upstream system to deal with the encoding problem.

Comment: Ryan! How the heck do you know so much about UTF8 that you are able to make this guess correctly!?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
mysql> SELECT HEX(name) FROM mytable;
+-----------+
| hex(name) |
+-----------+
| 4142C2A0  | 
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not try the BINARY operator?

"The BINARY operator casts the string following it to a binary string. This is an easy way to force a column comparison to be done byte by byte rather than character by character."

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the HEX() function [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex]. From the documentation, `SELECT HEX('abc');` returns `616263`.