# NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding to PHP - PHP to iOS Push Notification

Tags: php, ios, unicode, push-notification, emoji

in my app, i send a data encoding with **NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding** (for emoji etc.), save it in the database and return it when is requested. When i receive the data, i use the same encoding and everything is ok.

But, if i have to send a push notification from the PHP file, i don't know how convert this encoding in a normal encoding..for example:

> **Original text:** Hi guys {an emoji} ! è
>
> **Saved text (and after sent by push):** Hi guys \ud83d\ude0a ! \350

Can you help me?! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usw `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead of `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding`.

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14411280/451475)